# having trouble with this code/dice game. Idk why when i push the roll dice button it disappears and when i have an .css sheet link it wipes the page

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 seperate codes one is the html and the other is JavaScript. Im haveing trouble keeping the button to stay and when I add any kind of .css file to it for design it whipes it white and all i have left is the results. I am trying to make a simple craps game. I didnt add the .css sheet but you can just create any simple .css with it and see it whipes it white. And the button disappears.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <script src="pastedC.js"></script>
    <title>Casino 2</title>
</head>
<body>

    <button onclick="play();" class="play();">Roll the Dice</button>
    <p>
       

    </p>
</body>
</html>
```

js.file

```
function play() {
    var die1 = 5
    var die2 = 2

    var sum = die1+die2
    document.write("Die 1 = " + die1)
    document.write("<br/>")
    document.write("Die 2 = " + die2)
    document.write("<br/>")
    document.write("Sum = " + sum)
    document.write("<br/>")
    if (sum == 7 || sum == 11)
    { document.write("CRAPS - you lose")
    document.write("<br/>")
    }
    else if (die1== die2 && die1%2 == 0)
    {
    document.write("DOUBLES - you win")
    document.write("<br/>")
    }

    }
    document.write("Simple Craps")
    document.write("<br/>")
    play()
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is with **document.write**, when you say document.write after the document has loaded, it overwrites the existing document object entirely. If it run before that, it does not overwrite it.

What you can do, set the innerHtml of a specific element, something like: document.getElementById("container").innerHTML="generatedHTML";